# Azure tables filtering by partition key value

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I would like to filter value on an azure table where `partitionKey` is equal to a value.

```
var query = new azure.TableQuery().stringFilter('PartitionKey', 'eq', Tenant);
tableSvc.queryEntities(
    TABLE_VALUE,
    query,
    null,
    async function (error, result, response) {
    });
```

Actually I'm getting this error

```
'(intermediate value).stringFilter is not a function'
```